# Elixir: Date.to_string returns different formats for server in US and local server in UK

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I understand the api Date.to_string converts the given date to a string according to its calendar, so I get format "8/22/18" for a server hosted in US and "2018-07-30" for a local server in UK

Is there a way to retrieve the format from the calendar?

Comment: There's only one implementation of Calendar in Elixir core. Are you defining a different calendar or are you using a third party package which defines one?

Comment: @Dogbert I am not using any third party package which uses a different calendar.

Comment: @Dogbert could I borrow you're expertise in this and could check weather my answer is going down the right lines? thanks

Comment: @SamHouston yes, that's exactly what I found. The only way this could happen is if the other date struct is using a different instance of `Calendar`. The ISO Calendar, which is the default, should always format as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with always printing in the ISO 8601 format, you can use [`Date.to_iso8601`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Date.html#to_iso8601/2). If not, I suggest you use the [`Timex`](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) library instead (see [formatting](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/formatting.html#content) in particular):

```
iex> Timex.format({2013,8,18}, "{YYYY}-{M}-{D}")
{:ok, "2013-8-18"}
```

Comment: This is what I have done as a part of the fix, but the problem is legacy data. I need to migrate previous data to this format which needs recognition of the existing time format

Comment: @DigvijayUpadhyay please extend your question with input examples and expected output

Answer (score 1):

From digging into the source code, I found that `Date.to_string(~D[2018-07-30])` will always return the string `"2018-07-30"` no matter which country you run it from.

If you look into where `Date.to_string` comes from (by following: [Date.to_string](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.7.1/lib/elixir/lib/calendar/date.ex#L244)
then [date_to_string](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/d91aed218eca24aea8a0402aee0418be61edd93c/lib/elixir/test/elixir/fixtures/calendar/holocene.exs#L27))

We find that the function simply returns:

```
"#{year}-#{month}-#{day}"
```